# Error in extract_function(initial_response) : no query results returned in elasticsearchr in R

Tags: r, elasticsearch, querydsl

I have an index in elastic search and want to get specific driver age people. I executed the following query to get drv_age = 63

```
library(elasticsearchr)

# Required variables;
index.name <- "acturial"
index.type <- "data"
col.name <- "drv_age"
value <- 63

# Path where result will be written in json form;
path <- "G:\\R Projects\\Elastic Search R\\Record.json"

myQuery <- paste0('{ "match" : {"', col.name, '" : ', value , '} } ')

# reading data from elasticSearch
data <- elastic("http://localhost:9200", index.name, index.type) %search% query(myQuery)
```

It works fine but when I put drv_age = 10000 which is not in the index then It gives me

> Error in extract_function(initial_response) : no query results returned

My problem is to store that error message in a variable to process it. But I am not able to do it.

Answer (score 2):

Using search method of the elastic package in R we can get total hits against a query. In this way, we can check whether any data is found or not. Following is the code snippet.

```
library(elastic)

connect()

# Required variables;
index.name <- "acturial"
index.type <- "data"
col.name <- "year"
value <- "2013"

myQuery <- paste(col.name,value,sep = ":")

records.found <- Search(index.name,index.type,q=myQuery)$hits$total

if (records.found > 0){
# Your loggic;
}else{
print("No record found")
}
```